# Unknown MSBuild failure while building Xamarin Mobile App

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, msbuild

I had this `Unknown MSBuild failure.Please try building the project again` while building Xamarin Form App. To be sure, I created a new app from a blank app template. It was also failed to build. Other web app and console app are okay to be built.

I have macOS High Sierra 10.13.6. And Xcode 10.1 (10B61). Due to my MacBook Pro hardware limitation, I could not update Xcode to the latest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out that it might be due to the latest Xamarin.Android Update. So I try to downgrade it to Version: 11.2.2.1. Then there is no more Unknown MSBuild error. I had the error with Xamarin Android 11.3.0.4. I guess the latest versions are not compatible with my hardware. Already I can only use Xamarin.iOS Version: 12.6.0.25 because I only have macOS High Sierra 10.13.6. And Xcode 10.1 (10B61).

You may get the old versions of Xamarin Android and iOS here at Xamarin's Github.

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android#downloads

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios#downloads

Hope your `Unknown MSBuild error` is resolved that way.